# I want to shift my focus to other textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have 2 date pickers in single page now when i click on datepicker2 i check if it has selected datepicker1 if not then try to shift the focus to textbox1 but it is still focus at textbox2
here is my code 
HTML

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-3"> </div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
<div class="form-horizontal">


<div class="control-group">

    <div class="controls">
        <div class="input-group">
            <label for="date-picker-1" class="input-group-addon btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>

            </label>
            <input id="date-picker-1" type="text" class="date-picker form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
<div class="form-horizontal">


<div class="control-group">

    <div class="controls">
        <div class="input-group">
            <label for="date-picker-2" class="input-group-addon btn"><span id="calender2" class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>

            </label>
            <input id="date-picker-2" type="text" class="date-picker form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>

  </div>
```

Javascript

```
$("#date-picker-1").datepicker({
dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"
});
$("#date-picker-1").on("change", function () {
var id = $(this).attr("id");
var timePicker1Value=document.getElementById("date-picker-1").value.trim();
if (timePicker1Value ==""){
    showMessage("green", "Please select 'From Date' first", "");
}
var val = $("label[for='" + id + "']").text();
$("#msg").text(val + " changed");
});

$( "#calender2" ).off("click").on("click",function() {

var timePicker1Value=document.getElementById("date-picker-1").value.trim();
if (timePicker1Value ==""){
    showMessage("green", "Please select 'From Date' first", "");
    $("#date-picker-1").focus();
}
else
{ 
    $("#date-picker-2").datepicker({
          dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"


    });
     datepicker2();
 }

 });


function datepicker2(){
$("#date-picker-2").on("change", function () {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");


    var val = $("label[for='" + id + "']").text();
    $("#msg").text(val + " changed");
});
 }
```

Comment: are you getting your message "Please select 'From Date' first" ?

Comment: yes I  am getting the message but focus is at the second textbox

Comment: I know it may not be proper solution, but try to put a `return` or `e.preventDefault()` after you focus 1st datepicker. to use `e.preventDefault()` you should pass `e` as parameter to click callback function of date-picker-2

Comment: Thanks man e.preventDefault() worked...

Comment: Great, if you find someone's post in answers really worked for your question then please mark it as answer. Or you can always upvote an answer or comment if it has helped you getting the answer. It's kind of boosts people to help more.